# Allegation or Mixture Proportion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

15 Litres of Milk is drawn out of a Jar and filled with water.This operation is performed 1 more times.If the Ratio of the quantity of milk left in jar to that of water in jar is 16:9,what was the initial quantity of milk present in the jar

I have tried:

Two times of Milk is drawn out the jar, so 30 litres of milk should be drawn out and some amount of water is added,but the water added in the ratio should be if milk is 4 parts and water is 3 parts,How to guide for the answer

Comment: As I understand 30 liters of milk were taken and replaced with water? So you should have $(x-30)/30=16/9$ which solves $x=83.333...$ so there were 83 and one third liters of milk?

Comment: @Matta answer is 75 litres

Comment: @anyone noone answer for the question how to solve till now

Answer (score 0):

Final ratio is 16:9 so total volume can be taken as 25x.

So 
final concerntration of milk $= 25x*[1- \frac{15}{25x}] *[1- \frac{15}{25x}]$

$16x = 25x*[1- \frac{15}{25x} ] *[1- \frac{15}{25x} ]$

$\frac{16}{25} = [1- \frac{15}{25x} ]^2$

$\frac{4}{5} = [1- \frac{15}{25x}]$

$\frac{1}{5} = \frac{15}{25x}$

Total volume, $ 25x=15*5=75$.  Ans

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).